# Minimizing the product $xy$ subject to a polynomial constraint on $x, y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $$16y(x^2+1)=25x(y^2+1),$$ where $x,y$ are positive integers, find the smallest possible value of $xy$.

I wrote my expression as a quadratic in $x$ and calculated it in form of $y$. Then $xy$ became in $y$ but it had square roots, so differentiating it and then solving and then substituting didn't seem a feasible method.

Comment: Nope, I have no idea what they are?

Comment: @Garvil Please disregard, I didn't see the integral condition, and the method is inappropriate for solving this (modulo my above comment).

Comment: @Travis the minimum in positive reals is quite obviously $0$ when $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$.  Don't see why positive integer solutions should be anywhere close :(

Comment: Garvil and Travis, the solution is displayed in my "Answer."

Comment: What answer? All I see is 'The minimum values are x=8 and y=5....'

Comment: Yes.  The problem asks for the solution with the minimum $xy$.  I provided the answer.

Comment: Why the down vote? I answered the problem as stated. Geez, someone tries to help, gets the answer sought, explains the algorithm in a comment, and gets punished. Explain please. –

Comment: Is this another secret source problem, Garvil? Are we helping you cheat?

Comment: This problem was asked in one of Indian Olympiads quite a time back. I don't know which year, and its solution is not available online. That is why I asked it here.

Comment: And I answered it here and explained the very sound methodology I used.  So I am puzzled as to the reason that it received a vote down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first note that $x > y > 1.$ Since $(y, y^2+1) = 1,$ we have $y\mid 25x,$ and similarly, $x\mid 16y.$ Suppose that $5\not\mid y,$ so that $y\mid x.$ Writing $x = ky$ yields $ky\mid 16y \Rightarrow k\mid 16,$ and clearly $k\not = 1.$ Hence we now have $16y(k^2y^2+1) = 25ky(y^2+1),$ which after rearranging becomes

$$y^2(16k-25) = 25 - \frac{16}{k}.$$

Since $k \ge 2,$ the LHS is at least $7y^2$ while the right-hand side is less than $25,$ so $y = 1,$ which is impossible. Hence $5\mid y.$

Suppose that $25\not\mid y.$ Now $y = 5y' \Rightarrow y' \mid 5x \Rightarrow y' \mid x.$ Then $x = ky'$ and $ky' \mid 80y' \Rightarrow k\mid 80.$ Since $x > y, k > 5.$ Using $y = 5y'$ and $x = ky'$ in the original equality yields

$$80y'(k^2y'^2 +1) = 25ky'(25y'^2+1)$$

which, after rearrangement, becomes

$$y'^2(16k-125) = 5 - \frac{16}{k}.$$

As $k>5,$ the RHS is positive, which implies that $k\ge 8.$ But then $k = 8$ (otherwise the LHS is bigger than $5$), whence $y' = 1$ gives $y = 5, x = 8.$

Now if $25\mid y,$ then $x \ge 2$ so $xy \ge 50$ is bigger than the product $5\cdot 8 = 40,$ so we're done.